# GiLab CI - Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Few tests are failing in pipeline with error `Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)`.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: starefossen/ruby-node:latest

services:
  - mongo:latest
  - redis:latest

variables:
  MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongo:27017/db_test
  REDISTOGO_URL: redis://localhost:6379

before_script:
  - bundle install --path=cache/bundler
  - cp config/mongoid.yml.gitlab config/mongoid.yml
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate

test:
  script:
   - bundle exec rake test
```

my `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` file

```
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-status'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { size: 5, url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Throttler, storage: :redis
  end
  config.redis = { size: 10, url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] }
end
```

can anyone point me the right direction? Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the redis URL to be `redis://redis:6379` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: @nattfodd that worked, care adding an answer? I will accept it

Comment: yeap, added full answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no one single localhost in Docker which is used by Gitlab CI. The convention is that the service name declared below will be available for other containers in the docker network by it's name - `redis` in that case:

```
services:
  - redis:latest
```

So replacing `localhost` with `redis` should be enough:

```
variables:
-   REDISTOGO_URL: redis://localhost:6379
+   REDISTOGO_URL: redis://redis:6379
```